# Can't ping local devices by network name after DNS change

Tags: network, wifi, dns

Today I was changing the Wifi network adapter settings to give my MacBook Pro a static IP address on the local network (disabling DHCP), and for this I had to add the DNS servers that I looked up in my router's admin interface.

Upon adding the first DNS server with the "+" icon in the DNS tab of the adapter advanced properties, all the entries that were already present in the list of DNS servers vanished without me taking notice of what they were. (I figured they weren't so important). So I added both DNS servers provided by my router's status page as well as the router IP address (you never know).

After applying the parameters, I noticed I could not ping my Raspberry Pi with it's network name `raspberrypi` anymore, nor could I connect via SSH to it with this name. I have to use the IP address instead.

This leads me to believe I lost a DNS server in the process. How can I find out which DNS server to add in order to be able to ping devices by network name again?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you use "Using DHCP with manual address" instead of pure Manual?

Comment: @Tetsujin exactly the same. I actually first tried this option before switching to manual but both cases present the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your router's DNS servers won't know about your private device names, but chances are your router will. Add your royter's IP address to the list of DNS servers and drag it to
the top of the list.

Comment: That was it! I had already put my router's IP address in the list but it was in last position. Dragging it to the top did the trick, thanks!

Comment: The reason you have to drag it to the top is that OS X only works through the list if the server isn't available. If it finds the first DNS server, and that server doesn't know the name, then it just stops there.